# How to set dynamic schema name in JDBC Kafka source connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, hana

I am using SAP HANA source connector `"connector.class":"com.sap.kafka.connect.source.hana.HANASourceConnector"` to import data into kafka topics.

I want to have costume name/namespace for avro schemas that being created by the connector. Therefore, I've used the `SetSchemaMetadata` function to transform the schema name.

here is an example of my connector configuration:

```
 "key.converter.schemas.enable": true,
 "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
 "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xx.xx.xx/schema/",
 "key.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support": true,
 "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
 "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xx.xx.xx/schema/",
 "value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support": true,


 "transforms":"SetSchemaMetadata",
 "transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
 "transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name":"com.company.kafka.avro.table",
    
 "table1.table.name": "\"database\".\"schema.table1\"",
 "table2.table.name": "\"database\".\"schema.table2\"",
```

This will result that both schemas (table1-value & table2-value) will have the namespace "com.company.kafka.avro" and name "table"

is there anyway to make the schema name the same as topic name? something like: `"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name":"com.company.kafka.avro.${topic}",`

or is there anyway to specifiy it manually for each topic and schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way that I know to do this. Instead create a separate connector for each of the tables.